# uploads a local file to a block blob

Tags: c#, azure, windows-10-iot-core, azure-blob-storage

Im using an example from this link :
 https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fazure%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fazure_breadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-dotnet&tabs=windows

it works fine on local device , and i can upload a file to azure. but when i run the app on the raspberry pi , i get an error while trying to upload the file :

- ex  {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__c`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
  at App10.MainPage.d__31.MoveNext()
  Request Information
  RequestID:df2e03db-101e-0128-4a45-c640d2000000
  RequestDate:Sat, 16 Feb 2019 12:06:26 GMT
  StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
  ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
  ErrorMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
  RequestId:df2e03db-101e-0128-4a45-c640d2000000
  Time:2019-02-16T22:14:38.5545020Z
  }   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the authentication, in the original article Microsoft tell you to call `setx storageconnectionstring "<yourconnectionstring>"`, have you made it on raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

The sample works for me with following steps.

1. Replace the variable `storageConnectionString` with the connection string of my storage.
2. Run command `dotnet publish -r win10-arm` to publish the app for windows iot core.
3. Copy the folder `storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win10-arm\publish` to the device.
4. Run the storage-blobs-dotnet-quickstart.exe via powershell connected with device.

It would works fine. Please try again. If the error appears again, feel free let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. 
both of you are right. because the time was not set right azure reject the request. after setting the time the RP have managed to send the data to blob. tnx !